# Consuming SOAP Web Service with WS-Security Dynamically through js

Tags: javascript, soap, soap-client

**Requirement:**

1. Customer to give the SOAP Web-service's WSDL at runtime i.e pick the
   WSDL file from a file share location.
2. Consume the WSDL, and call the Method chosen by the Customer on the
   UI and handle the response.

Comment: Welcome ! It is not clear what the question is here.

Comment: I am having a JS App where the user will be giving a link to the WSDL file, and according to that file, the user will be provided with the list of available functions. From which they can select the function they need and get the data from the web service.